# Is it possible to turn on directory indexes when serving static files in development in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm currently using the `staticfiles_urlpatterns` to serve static files in development, as recommended, but I'm getting 404's on the static files for a particular app I'm using and not sure why... turning on directory indexes for all the static files would be cool if its possible.    I noticed the ['show_indexes' option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/static-files/#django.views.static.serve) for serving some types of static files.  Is it possible to write my debug-only url conf in a way that enables this across the board for my static files in development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work (update to use STATIC_ROOT):

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
            'show_indexes': True,
        }),
   )
```